# Escape characters in a q-lang query via Python

Tags: python, escaping, kdb

I have issues applying escape sequences in a query to a kdb server.

The native query is:

```
select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, not cond like "*[BMPQTUWZ]*", corr <= 1
```

Any help is welcomed.

I am using Python to send it, and I put \" for " in the query in order to transmit the double quote sign:

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

query = 'select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, not cond like \"*[BMPQTUWZ]*\", corr <= 1'

#query = '\"2+2\"'


print('Attempt to open a connection...')

q = qconnection.QConnection(host=server, port=server_port, username=user, password=server_password, timeout=server_timeout, pandas = True)
q.open()
print('Connection established...')

print('Attempt to send the query', query)
df = pd.DataFrame(q.sendSync(query))
print('Query <<', query, '>> sent...')
```

Output for '"2+2"' and output for 'select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, not cond like \"*[BMPQTUWZ]*\", corr <= 1' is listed below.

```
PS G:\atom-projects\test> python.exe .\test-1.py
Attempt to open a connection...
Connection established...
Attempt to send the query "2+2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test-1.py", line 23, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(q.sendSync(query))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 509, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!


PS G:\atom-projects\test> python.exe .\test-1.py
Attempt to open a connection...
Connection established...
Attempt to send the query select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, not cond like "*[BMPQTUWZ]*", corr <= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test-1.py", line 23, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(q.sendSync(query))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\qpython\qconnection.py", line 303, in sendSync
    response = self.receive(data_only = False, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\qpython\qconnection.py", line 380, in receive
    result = self._reader.read(**self._options.union_dict(**options))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\qpython\qreader.py", line 138, in read
    message = self.read_header(source)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\qpython\qreader.py", line 158, in read_header
    header = self._read_bytes(8)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\qpython\qreader.py", line 388, in _read_bytes
    data = self._stream.read(length)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Now, I have trouble with escape characters.

If I send the query to the kdb server.

```
query = 'select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, corr <= 1'
```

the query is transmitted. But when I add **not cond like \"*[BMPQTUWZ]*\"**, there is an error.

*OS and Python language details:*
Windows 10, x64, Python 3.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping works fine for me:

```
q)t:([]sym:100?`1;cond:100#`Buy`Sell`Example;corr:100?2f;price:100?100f)
q)t
sym cond    corr      price   
------------------------------
n   Buy     1.339583  82.48839
m   Sell    1.17743   95.01603
a   Example 1.135715  54.35053
o   Buy     0.7889166 29.12758
b   Sell    1.851226  45.29782
…

df = q.sendSync('select hi:max price, lo:min price, cond:first cond  by sym from t where not cond like \"[BS]*\"')

df
    hi  lo  cond
sym             
b'a'    64.230790   24.164567   b'Example' 
b'b'    60.669536   12.766243   b'Example'
b'c'    85.688555   79.785111   b'Example'
b'd'    83.056125   83.056125   b'Example' 
b'e'    73.149409   73.149409   b'Example'
b'f'    93.359214   36.638445   b'Example' 
...
```

The `'\"2+2\"'` fails because 4 is returned and this can't be presented in a DataFrame.

Your select seems to be failing due a timeout. Perhaps try increasing your time out.

Also what are you trying to achieve with the select? My example is not where cond starts with either B or S. So only returns Example.

Conor's suggestion above may be faster and better if cond is a single character column and not a symbol. If it is a symbol column like mine above with whole words. `Like/Regex` must be used.

Comment: It turned out the short timeout period was the reason. May be because of the fact the query is more complex.

So your suggestion is the answer which solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the square brackets?

query = 'select lo:min price, hi:max price by sym from trade where date = 2007.02.28, not cond like \"*\[BMPQTUWZ\]*\", corr <= 1'

Comment: Yes, I have tried, although square brackets are not escape symbols.

Comment: I've updated my answer which had a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run something like:

...where not cond in \"BMPQTUWZ\"

Comment: Most probably you are right as the query is successful. I need to make some more runs, and then I shall confirm your answer as the one which is the best.

The fact is I was given this query (I haven't made it) and I thought it is a good one.

Comment: The square brackets are needed, otherwise the meaning is changed.